# Create objects of wrapper classes with java 9

Tags: java, wrapper, java-9

One new feature of Java 9 is to deprecate the constructor of wrapper objects. The only way to create new Wrapper objects is to use their `valueOf()` static methods. 
For example for Integer objects, `Integer.valueOf` implements a cache for the values between -128 and 127 and returns the same reference every time you call it.

As API for `Integer` class says "The static factory valueOf(int) is generally a better choice, as it is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance." and JLS says "*Given a value of the corresponding primitive type, it is generally unnecessary to construct new instances of these box classes. The recommended alternatives to construction are autoboxing or the valueOf static factory methods. In most cases, autoboxing will work, so an expression whose type is a primitive can be used in locations where a box class is required*"

But what happens with the values outside this range? 
For example Integer x = Integer.valueOf(456) is a new object every time the class was executed?

Answer (score 6):

Both

```
Integer x = Integer.valueOf(456);
```

and

```
Integer x = 456;
```

will always result in a new instance of `Integer` being created, since `456` is outside the range of the `Integer` cache.

You can test it by writing

```
Integer x1 = Integer.valueOf(456);
Integer x2 = Integer.valueOf(456);
System.out.println(x1==x2);
```

which will print `false`.

Comment: @silviaDominguez What do you mean by "always go to head"?

Comment: Sorry I meant heap . I mean this object will be always  created every time was called

Comment: @silviaDominguez If by "always go to heap" you mean that always a new object is created, that's true (though the Javadoc allows implementations of Java to cache values outside the -128 to 127 range, but in practice I haven't seen such additional caching).

Comment: This topic is more complicated. As said, implementations are allowed (and even encouraged), but not required to implement caching for values outside the range. But caching could be implemented in two ways, in Java code, as the mandatory caching is implemented, or by the JVM knowing the special contract of `valueOf`, only applied to optimized code. But even if a JVM implements such caching behavior when optimizing, it interferes with other optimizations, e.g. not doing caching combined with Escape Analysis allows to replace `Integer.valueOf(456)==Integer.valueOf(456)` with the constant `false`…

Answer (score 2):

First why bother with these details - the correct way to compare `Integer` objects is to use either:

`if (x.intValue() == y.intValue())` or better `x.equals(y)`

Don't rely on the fact that *there is a cache* under any circumstances, since this cache's *upper bound* can be changed as a property, you can see it via:

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal | grep AutoBoxCacheMax
```

Comment: I apologize if its stupid, but I am not able to correlate this with the question currently. Could you update with how this is related to the `Integer.valueOf` and its bound of caching.

Comment: @nullpointer no need to apoligize, I assumed since u create these objects, you would need to compare them at some point, so you *should* not care how many objects are created if you compare them correctly. I might hae done too many assumptions here, might be correct to delete this...

Comment: Or maybe link or comment to Eran's answer, which actually does a kind of comparison there. Where in the technique used by you should be good to prove facts?